# Which channels are scanned by Android's startScan method?

Tags: android, android-wifi, samsung-mobile, wpa-supplicant

I've been using the WifiManager#startScan method in Android and need to know how it works.  Specifically, I'd like to know the following.

1. What channels does it scan in the 2.4 GHz range?
2. What channels does it scan in the 5 GHz range?
3. What is the dwell time?

I looked through the AOSP source and traced it into the wpa_supplicant code, but I'm not sure if I'm on the right track.

I'm using a Samsung Galaxy Note 2 GT-N7105 running Android 4.1.2